# Faucet aerator's inside part popped out after increasing home's water pressure

Tags: water, repair, faucet, sink, water-pressure

This already happened a little while ago. We had an older Soviet era water pump with less water pressure which broke and we had to replace it with a new one. We replaced it with a modern one which has more water pressure up to 3.8 bars. Everything would be fine, if afterwards one of two of my home's faucets aerator's inside parts gradually didn't loosen until being pushed out completely. It didn't happen to the other one (bath's faucet and shower). Both faucets were quite new bought a year prior at the same time, same place, same manufacturer, similar looking, they both were fine before. I unnecessarily didn't want to unscrew bath's faucet aerator to see, if inside is different but from outside they are similar. I understand that the water volume was greater than what the aerator could let through so it pushed out. This is the first time something like this happens and that I have to separately deal with the aerator. I simply could buy a new one but this might happen again, so I want to make sure I buy the right one. What should I look for when buying a new one?

[image: 3 filter parts for aerator, I seperated them]

Comment: 1) Is there any manufacturer's warranty on the faucet? If so, you may be eligible for a warranty replacement. 2) It's a bit hard to tell from that pic, but it looks like those pieces just press in, usually, American ones screw in which helps hold them. Look to see if there are any threads on the inside of the faucet that you could screw them into. Beyond that, these are usually fairly standard parts and if the diameter/threads are right, any one will work.

Comment: One could put a pressure regulator downstream from the pump to lower the pressure into the house.